# What do Birds of Paradise do?

Tags: altos-odyssey

Occasionally while boarding, one or two birds will start following me. They’ll fly around for a short while before leaving. Missions refer to them as “Birds of Paradise”.

What do these birds do? Do they have any effect on gameplay?

[image: A bird of paradise flying]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what I've noticed, they are able to collect coins for you when flying through them. It's something like a weaker magnet powerup. The rest of their signigficance, if any, remains unknown to me though.

What is worth checking, but might as well be not applicable:
• they might give you points to your current combo when they start flying
• and/or they might give you points to your combo when they depart (think of it as successfully riding with them for the whole distance they fly with you)